# Android App Restart

Tags: android

I am developing a Timer based app. Timer runs continuously in one of the activity whether the app is in the foreground or background. A separate service is written to log GPS every one second using a separate timer. Activity timer is responsible for starting and stopping the service based on certain condition.  I have extended the Application class and overridden  the onCreate and onTerminate events.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application.
```

and 
AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="MyApplication"
         >
```

service

```
public class GPSLoggingService extends Service
```

When the app is running in background and sometimes in foreground, the onCreate is executed several times and if the service is running it also gets restarted.

What could be the reason of frequent restart of the app and firing of onCreate of MyApplication class. What is the solution of this problem?

Please help me since I am trying solve this problem for last 3 days

This is the complete androidmanifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ab.xy.cd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.0.5.15" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="MyApplication"
         >

        <!-- Since application is using map add following -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
            >
        </activity>
        <!--
             stateHidden is required if you dont want to show keyboard when activity starts and 
             edit text gets focus. In this case if user clicks on any edit text the on the same
             layout, the keyboard will be poped up 
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.BasicSettings"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Challenges"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Slim"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" 
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Score"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Settings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.TextSummary"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.EventSetting"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.AboutMapAndTraffic"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.VersionInformation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Language"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Search"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.TutorialFromLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ui.Tutorial"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ShutdownActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.ExtraFor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".GPSLoggingService"
            android:process=":gpslogging"
            >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="ab.xy.cd.utils.NetworkStateInformer"
            android:label="NetworkStateInformer" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="ab.xy.cd.utils.RushHourReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="ab.xy.cd.utils.ServiceStartReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="ab.xy.cd.utils.ServiceEndReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: hi why dont you use broadcast receiver for timer checking.

Comment: @user220461 it's not about your question but still: `onTerminate()` callback is for test puposes only, it would works only on emulator. Check this [description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate())

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Application.onCreate`? It's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Post the rest of your manifest (include the service and activity descriptions)

Comment: Are you sure your app is not destroyed due to exceptions and then restarted when you come back on it?

Comment: Ya, am sure the app is not destroyed due to exception